# Google Maps SDK for iOS: don't support little endian bitmaps

Tags: ios, google-maps, png

I'm trying to implement a `GMSTileLayer` subclass in the Google Maps for iOS SDK. I have a bunch of PNG images on disk that are for each tile in the tile layer, and they're loaded using `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`. When I try to load the images, they don't show up, and I get this message in the log:

```
2015-08-22 22:50:10.663 inPin[44718:24904635] ((null)) was false: Don't support little endian bitmaps
2015-08-22 22:50:10.663 inPin[44718:24904635] ((null)) was false: Unable to create GMSGLImageTile due to bad graphics data
```

I didn't know that PNG images even had endianness, so I don't know where this message is coming from. Anyone have an idea why this is happening? I tried a PNG from the Google tile servers and it worked fine. My PNGs are being generated by a script that uses ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Turns out my image had 16 bit color depth, and changing it to 8 bit made the error go away. In ImageMagick, I just had to add `-depth 8`.